# Sizing the UIViewController when I push it onto UINavigationController

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a UINavigationController which I'm using quite happily.  However I want to push a UIViewController onto the screen but I want it to be smaller than the existing one. The code I have below doesn't resize the new ViewController.  It's still displayed full screen.

```
public void DisplayEditWindow () {
    editViewController = new EditViewController(UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
    editViewController.View.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 600);
    navigationController.PushViewController (editViewController, true);
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something a bit daft but I cant see what.  All help greatly appreciated.

mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationController` does not work in this way.  `PresentModalViewController` would not work either, you would end up with a black screen where the other view was (unless you use a specific transition that works on iPad only).

The only way you can get this effect is to add a new sub-view to your existing view.  This is certainly more complicated, as you would have to manage dismissing it yourself and program any transition animations manually.

Comment: Thanks- thats what I did in the end.  I abandoned the Navigation controller and just added a View to the PresentModalController.